# Clean up knockout VM item before submitting to server

Tags: knockout.js

I am pretty new to knockout. But what I am trying to do is clean up a viewmodel before trying to send it back to the server. I have a couple of ko.observable & ko.computed fields I don't want to send back to the server (progress & entryType)

I have a button that is bound to this event. I start by finding the item in the vm based on its id. Deleting the not required fields is where I have my trouble.

```
 self.addTransaction = function(transaction) {

            var selected = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.transactions(), function(currentTransaction) {
                return currentTransaction.id() == transaction.id();
            });

            if (selected) {
                    console.log(selected);

                var items = ko.toJS(selected);
                var mappedItems = ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function(item) {
                    delete item.progress && item.entryType;
                    return item;
                });
                console.log(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(mappedItems), null, 2));
                //send to server                

            } 
        };
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how I can do this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

It allows you to specify a map to use when mapping, and you can tell it to ignore properties:

```
var mapping =
{
    'ignore': ["propertyToIgnore", "alsoIgnoreThis"]
};
var jsData = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel, mapping);
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. I overlooked the plugin!